# To find a distribution for the absolute difference between two exponentially distributed variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

I have two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are IIDs distributed with the common distribution $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda >0$. I was working to find a distribution of $|X_1−X_2|$.

I used convolution to find the function $f_Z(z)$ as
\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_x(x)*f_y(x-z)dx , \ for \ X_1 > X_2 \ \& \\
f_Z(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{-x}(x)*f_y(z+x)dx , \ for \ X_1 < X_2
\end{align}

Is this the correct method to do it & how to find the range of $z$?

Comment: $Z$ must be non-negative since it is an absolute value, and there is no upper bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By symmetry between $X_1$ and $X_2$ we can write $$P(|X_1-X_2| \leq z)$$ $$=2P(X_2 \leq X_1\leq X_2+z)$$ $$=2\int_0^{\infty}\int_{x_2}^{x_2+z} \lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda x_1}e^{-\lambda x_2}dx_1dx_2.$$ for $z>0$. I will let you do the computation.

Comment: I didn't understand how the lower limit of x1 became x2

Comment: @AbijithPY You have to integrate the joint density over the region $\{(x_1,x_2): x_2 \leq x_1 \leq x_2+z\}$.

Comment: Because $$\begin{align}P(\lvert X_1-X_2\rvert\leqslant z)&=2\,P(X_2\leqslant X_1\cap X_1-X_2\leqslant z)\\&=2\,P(X_2\leqslant X_1\leqslant X_2+z)\\&=2\int_0^\infty f_{X_2}(x_2)\,P(x_2\leqslant X_1\leqslant x_2+z)\,\mathrm d x_2\\&=2\int_0^\infty\int_{x_2}^{x_2+z} f_{X_2}(x_2)\,f_{X_1}(x_1)\,\mathrm d x_1\,\mathrm d x_2\end{align}$$

Comment: Okay thanks got it